# New to assembly language and having the error: "add.s:7: Error: shift expression expected -- `adds R0,R1,R2,R3'"

Tags: assembly, arm

I am writing my first assembly language program and I can't seem to find any good information about the error I am having. My code is posted below. Thanks in advance for the help!

```
.global _start
_start
    MOV R1, #5      @ Get 5 into R1
    MOV R2, #6      @ Get 6 into R2
    MOV R3, #7      @ Get 7 into R3
    ADDS R0, R1, R2, R3 @ Add the three, result in R0

    MOV R7, #1      @ exciters through sys call
    SWI 0
```

Comment: Consult an instruction set reference. Instructions are fixed form. `ADDS` does not take 4 operands.

Comment: Assembly does not have general purpose expression evaluation the way the higher level languages do.  Choices of operations/expressions are limited to what the hardware machine code can do as an instruction, or sequence of instructions, defined in the instruction set (though modulo what the assembler can compute as runtime constants, during compilation/assembly).

Comment: and arm is too generiic there are three to many arm instruction sets depending on how you count them.

Comment: with these register names you fall into one of two

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to @Jester, I adjusted my ADDS line and split it into 2 lines so I was able to give 3 operands each time I used ADDS.
Thank you!

Comment: you need to either post your answer or close the question as it is still left hanging

Answer (score 1):

It's expecting a shift because the only valid syntax for `adds` with three commas is a shift count for the 2nd source operand.  http://www.davespace.co.uk/arm/introduction-to-arm/barrel-shifter.html

Most ARM instructions, including `adds` take 2 inputs and write 1 output.  Asm has to map 1:1 with machine code so you can't add extra operand.  The 2nd input can be optionally shifted, but there can't be a 3rd addend.

```
int foo(int a, int b, int shift) {
    return a + (b<<shift);
}
```

[compiles to this asm](https://godbolt.org/z/hHp8Cx) (for ARM mode), with GCC9.2 -O3

```
foo:
        add     r0, r0, r1, lsl r2
        bx      lr
```

To add three numbers you need two `add` instructions, for the two `+` operations.  (unless the same number appears twice, in which case you can use a left-shifted input operand like `add  r0, r0, r1, lsl #1` to do `r0 + r1 + r1 = r0 + r1*2`)

You want something like this:

```
        add     r0, r1, r2
        adds    r0, r0, #7
```

(If this is Thumb mode, `adds` is more compact than `add`.)

ADD/ADDS supports an immediate operand, but of course not two immediate operands.  That would be useless, just use `mov r0, #5+6+7` to do the math at assemble time and use it as an immediate for a MOV instruction not ADDS.